# why is this namespace added by default "System.Collections.Generic"?

Tags: c#

Just a general curiosity question. Why is this namespace "System.Collections.Generic" added by default in Visual Studio when we create the project instead of let's say "System.Collections"?

Is Collection Classes under generics is most preferred way than the Collection Classes in the System.Collections?

Thanks
Harsha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, generics collection are better than regular collection because they bring strong typing, which prevent boxing and unboxing, and all those annoying casting.

There are few reason left to use a regular collection. Even if you don't know which type of object that you are storing, you can still use something like `List<object>`.

Comment: If you are given a non-generic collection, you can still invoke collection.Cast<TYPE>() to get back a strongly typed enumerator.

Answer (score 2):

Generic collections are far easier to use and it makes sense to me to have them included by default.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 2.0 added generic collections, which should completely replace the use of the non-generic collections in applications built for .NET 2.0 and beyond.

They have many advantages, especially since they bring strong typing and avoid boxing of value types.

As for why the namespace is added by default - I'd guess Microsoft decided to add this to encourage their use instead of the older System.Collections classes.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that if MS released the .NET BCL with the generic collection classes, many of the non-generic versions would not have been included.

Having said that, there is quite a lot of usage of `ArrayList` within Microsoft's code.

Comment: Those uses were written in C# 1, which did not support generics.  At that time, ArrayList was the only option.

Comment: Had the CLR been initially released with support for generics, there wouldn't have been any non-generic collections at all.

Comment: @SLaks -- that is not the case.  Use .NET Reflector and search for usages of `ArrayList` -- you will see it is used in the `System.ServiceModel` namespace that was included in .NET 3.0 (for WCF).  There must be certain cases where `ArrayList` outperforms `List<object>`.

Comment: You can also find a lot of usages within WPF, also introduced in .NET 3.0.